# How to manage scripts for each view in Angularjs ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router/stateProvider to load various views for a single page app.  Additionally I'm following what appears to be best practice for structuring code by breaking my code into components so I have, for example;

- Index.html
- \Components

  - \Component1

    - \page1.html
    - \page1.css
    - \page1-controllers.js
    - \page1-directives.js
  - \Component2

    - \page2.html
    - \page2.css
    - \page2-controllers.js
    - \page2-directives.js

I have quite a few different views/components (10+) and my question really relates to how to manage the loading of the js files (and the CSS files for that matter).  I can put the JS files all in  tags in the `index.html` file and all works fine, but looks a bit messy as it is a very long list.

So my question is:  How should I manage the inclusion of the various scripts for each view; should they all remain in the `index.html` file or is there a better way of managing them, such as loading only when each view is called via the ui-router?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use **RequireJs**, I will include a couple of sites with the documentation that explain how implement that.

http://www.javascripthtml.com/load-dynamically-javascript-file-in-angularjs-with-requirejs/

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/backbone.js/tutorials/organizing-backbone-using-modules

Comment: Thanks @Ronald, I'll have a look at the links - so seems that there is no native way to do this using ui-router and a requirement for additional libraries to manage script loading

Answer (score 0):

For css you may want to add a single class to each view then use a single css file for all views. I keep the css organized into modules for easy access. This will also help load times as it will require less requests.

For js I would create a universal js file that contains any code that is required for ALL views, then create individual js files for individual views. There really isn't a "right" way per se but preferred ways depending on the developers you work with. Keep it simple and easy for other developers to read. :)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem as you, I think that the only solution for us is to add the script in the "index.hmtl" page.